# What order does Angular match routes when loading feature modules?

Tags: angular

When I startup my application, its navigating to the ItdeptComponent, but I would have thought it would have routed to the HomeComponent?

Say I have routes defined for the root app like this:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [    
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'it', component: ItdeptComponent },
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Then, in a feature module, some routes like this

```
const itappRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'it', component: ItdeptComponent },
    { path: 'itblog', component: ItBlogPostListComponent },
    { path: 'editpost', component: EditBlogPostComponent },
    { path: 'createpost', component: CreateBlogPostComponent },
    { path: '', component: ItdeptComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(itappRoutes);
```

[**update**]

```
root module routes<br/>
const appRoutes: Routes = [    
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'it', component: ItdeptComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

feature module routes:

```
const itappRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'it', component: ItdeptComponent },
    { path: 'itblog', component: ItBlogPostListComponent },
    { path: 'editpost', component: EditBlogPostComponent },
    { path: 'createpost', component: CreateBlogPostComponent },
    ***{ path: '', redirectTo:'/it', pathMatch: 'full' } ];***
```

***remove last route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `redirectTo` instead of just specifying the component

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },

{ path: '', redirectTo: '/it', pathMatch: 'full' },
```

In the respective modules. Hope it helps.

Comment: yes, but doesn't that result int two different routes with the same path?  If I remove the '' empty path in the feature module, things work as expected.

Comment: when you are in the feature module, you are already routed to `/it`, so the default path `''`to be specified there should be declared as a children. See [this](https://angular.io/guide/router#child-route-configuration) for more info on how to declare them as children and apply the `redirectTo` within those childres routes